# guys, please,I can't wrap my hand around this, ipware, javascript and express

Tags: javascript, express, ip

so, I am trying to do something with express, more specifically, I am trying to get a user's ip address, but something isn't working and I can't figure out what is wrong, I am sure that it's an error, since when I try to access the app through the localhost, it says to me :

```
Cannot GET /
```

here are the things that come up in the console:

```
express app listening at http://localhost:443
{
  cleanup_ip: [Function (anonymous)],
  is_loopback_ip: [Function (anonymous)],       
  is_private_ip: [Function (anonymous)],        
  is_valid_ipv4: [Function (anonymous)],        
  is_valid_ipv6: [Function (anonymous)],        
  is_valid_ip: [Function (anonymous)],
  get_headers_attribute: [Function (anonymous)],
  get_local_ip: [Function (anonymous)],
  get_ip: [Function (anonymous)],
  get_trusted_ip: [Function (anonymous)]
}
```

and here's the code:

```
const express = require('express');
var get_ip = require('ipware');
const app = express();
const port = 443;



app.use('/', function(req, res, next) {
    
    var ipInfo = get_ip(req);
    console.log(ipInfo);
    //dovrebbe stampare a console l'ip dell'utente
    next();
});

app.listen( port, () => {
    console.log(`express app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

also, I found a message that visual studio code is telling me, it says:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'ipware'. 'c:/Users/ascar/Desktop/programming/app.js/node_modules/ipware/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm i --save-dev @types/ipware` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'ipware';`
```

the only problem is that the npm i --save-dev @types/ipware gives me this error:

```
'@types/ipware@*' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

I don't know how to do these things and I was hoping you guys could tell me what to do.
pls help guys! I have faith in u guys

Answer (score 1):

You have no route handler on `GET /`, you have to define at least one route :

```
app.get("/", (req,res) => res.send("Hello"));
```